# Saving Telegram Bot messages into google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm a beginner, so I'll try my best to explain what happends in the code and what I want to do. I've created a telegram bot and I want to save all the message log into google spreadsheets. I'm using Google App Scripts for this. The problem is that when I'm using the following code, only the messages that I write are saved into google sheets, it happends in the "doPost" function. What I want to do is  to save also the messages I receive from the bot. I tried adding the same code the I used in "doPost" and worked into the function "sendText" but I'm still unable to save the messages that the bot sends. How can I do this? here's my code:

```
var token = "...";     // 1. FILL IN YOUR OWN TOKEN
var telegramUrl = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token;
var webAppUrl = "..."; // 2. FILL IN YOUR GOOGLE WEB APP ADDRESS
var ssId = "...";      // 3. FILL IN THE ID OF YOUR SPREADSHEET
var adminID = "...";   // 4. Fill in your own Telegram ID for debugging

// connect to bot
function getMe() {
  var url = telegramUrl + "/getMe";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}

function setWebhook() {
  var url = telegramUrl + "/setWebhook?url=" + webAppUrl;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}

// make the bot to send a message
function sendText(id,text) {
  var url = telegramUrl + "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + id + "&text=" + encodeURIComponent(text);
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
  try {
    // this is where telegram works
    var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    var text = data.message.text;
    var id = data.message.chat.id;
    var name = data.message.chat.first_name + " " + data.message.chat.last_name;
    var answer = "Hi " + name;
    // sendText(id,answer);
    SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheets()[0].appendRow([new Date(),id,name,text,answer]);
    
    if(/^@/.test(text)) {
      var sheetName = text.slice(1).split(" ")[0];
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheetByName(sheetName) ? SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheetByName(sheetName) : SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).insertSheet(sheetName);
      var newText = text.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ");
      sheet.appendRow([new Date(),id,name,newText,answer]);
      sendText(id,"your text '" + newText + "' is now added to the sheet '" + sheetName + "'");
    }
  } catch(e) {
    sendText(adminID, JSON.stringify(e,null,4));
  }
}

function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("Hi there");  
}

// send a message from me to the bot
function doPost(e) {
  try {
    // this is where telegram works
    var data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
    var text = data.message.text;
    var id = data.message.chat.id;
    var name = data.message.chat.first_name + " " + data.message.chat.last_name;
    var answer = "Hi " + name;
    // sendText(id,answer);
    SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheets()[0].appendRow([new Date(),id,name,text,answer]);
    
    if(/^@/.test(text)) {
      var sheetName = text.slice(1).split(" ")[0];
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheetByName(sheetName) ? SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheetByName(sheetName) : SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).insertSheet(sheetName);
      var newText = text.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ");
      sheet.appendRow([new Date(),id,name,newText,answer]);
      sendText(id,"your text '" + newText + "' is now added to the sheet '" + sheetName + "'");
    }
  } catch(e) {
    sendText(adminID, JSON.stringify(e,null,4));
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: which function is the entry? this is just bunch of function definitions.. where is the server endpoint you set as webhook?

Comment: @Tibebes.M Thank you for your replay, I'm not sure what you mean, I'm using google apps script, so I just press "Publish" and then "Deploy As Web App", and I don't need to specify anything else.

Comment: Oh, I understand now after [reading this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web).. sorry, I assumed they were like GCP cloud function

Comment: @Tibebes.M The entry is `doPost`

Comment: Is your script being triggered by the telegram bot? Please add to the question enough details to understand what your code does, how it works and where do you get stuck including the relevant messages logged in the execution page.  (You should not require us to watch the referred Youtube video and assume that you followed the instrucctions without missing any step)

Comment: @Ruben I'm sorry the post wan't informative enough. Since I'm new to this, I'm trying my best to explain the problem and what I want to do.As I mentioned, I'm trying to save into google sheets the messages the bot sends to me. I'm able to save the messages I send to the bot using the code in the doPost and it is working, I tried to do the same in the function sendText where the bot messages are sent from, but it doesn't workd, and I'm not sure why. I hope it is more clear now that I've edited my post. Thank you for your help.

Comment: So basically ```doPost()``` works well as you get the messages the bot receives from the user but the function ```sendText()``` does not work well as it is not saving the messages sent from the bot right? Could you please log the ```text``` parameter before executing the rest of that function and let me know if you get something? Like this: ```function sendText(id,text) {Logger.log(text);``` Thanks ! :D

Comment: @MateoRandwolf Thank you for your comment, I tried that, unfortunately it still doesn't work. and when I do this switching, even my messages aren't saved into the log for some reason

Comment: So you dont get anything if you log ```text```? What does it print in the Logger if you log the event ```Logger.log(e);``` in ```doPost()```? Maybe you cant see your logs because this is an event and you are trying to see your logs from the IDE. Try the following to see your logs : In the Apps Script menu bar select View->StackDrive logging and run your project again.